# EntityFramework - composite foreign key and composite key on the same columns but with different order

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, primary-key

I've got a code first class like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    // first column of primary key, second column of foreign key to class 2
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    // second column of primary key, first column of foreign key to class 2
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    // first column of primary key
    public string Property2_1 { get; set; }
    // second column of primary key
    public string Property2_2 { get; set; }
    public string Property2_3 { get; set; }
}
```

I know it sounds weird, but is it possible to have a primary key on property1 (col 1) and property 2 (col2) and a foreign key on property 2(col 1) and property 1 (col2)?
if so, how do I declare it?

Comment: Foreign key to what? In order to get meaningful answer, show two sample classes with navigation properties involved in the FK relationship.

Comment: is it clearer now?

Comment: It was clear from the beginning, I just needed concrete example in order to provide concrete answer. Do you have a navigation property like `public Class2 Class2 { get; set; }` in `Class1`?

Comment: yeah there is one. sorry for late answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible with Fluent API (which currently is [the only way to configure Composite PK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys) anyway).

First, the PK configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Class2>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.Property2_1, e.Property2_2 });

modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.Property1, e.Property2 });
```

Then the FK configuration (it's hard to tell exactly the type of the relationship w/o navigation properties, so assuming `Class1` (many) <-> (one) `Class2`):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>()
    .HasOne<Class2>()
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Property2, e.Property1 });
```

Just make sure to use the correct `Has` / `With` overloads in case you have navigation properties.